# How to Turn Number into a String with Format?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Say I have a number, double, or NSNumber, 3.333333

I want that to turn that into @"3.3"

How would I do so?

Can I do NSString stringWithFormat? But what's the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0.0f` means the amount of digits before and after the decimal. So @Wevah's answer would be correct, but keeping that in mind will save you time in the future.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", yourDouble];
```

or for NSNumber:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", [yourNSNumber doubleValue]];
```

Comment: For further info, check out [formatting](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943-SW1) in the string programming guide.

Answer (score 1):

%f stands for a float variable which I am sure you understand. What you would need to display this is a float variable because it contains a decimal. Like people have stated before, you will need to use %.1f
The % just tells the compiler that a special character is coming up.
The f tells the compiler that it is a float variable.
The .1 tells the compiler how many decimal places your float variable is to have. If you would want to have 6 decimal places, then you would us %.6f

Yes, you will want to use string with format.
Say you have a UILabel, then you will want to say

```
theLabel'sName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", ((float)int1 / int2)];
```

You need the (float) to tell the compiler that whatever int1 / int2 is, is a float variable.

Answer (score 0):

If your `NSNumber` instance is called `myNumber` then do

```
[myNumber stringValue];
```